# Qwebkit links with .org do not work

Tags: windows, qt, qwebview, qwebkit, qwebpage

I just posted this over at QT Forum but SO usually answers faster :)

I have a strange issue. I use Qwebkit and a subclassed QWebPage. Any links such as .co.uk work fine but .org do not. They work on the development machines Windows 8 (64 bit) and Windows 7(32 bit) - the QT environment is on that machine. I use the deployment method of:

set PATH=C:\Qt\5.4\mingw491_32\bin;%PATH%

then

C:\Qt\5.4\mingw491_32\bin\windeployqt.exe --webkit2 --dir C:\pathToApp C:\pathToApp\applicationName.exe

Note that if I set a link to someDomainNameHere.co.uk it will work if I set a link to someDomainNameHere.org it will not work (Likewise with .gov.uk as well I see to remember).

Totally confused! How do I start to debug that? The same application and links works on a Mac without the QT environment.

Using Burpsuite as a proxy I can see that clicking on the .org domain link on a machine that does not work shows that no traffic is generated but a .co.uk domain does show the requests to be forwarded.

Really stuck on this one. I am sure I have tested on an old windows vista machine and the app works fine (no QT on there).

There is usually no proxy involved on any of the above machines. Not sure where to start to trouble shoot!

Thx in advance.

Comment: Definitely related to ssl but not sure why it works on some machines and not others. I need to set the ignore ssl errors or something like that. Will post back later if I have the answer. Where is the ignore ssl errors set?

Answer (score 0):

Solved from https://forum.qt.io/topic/17139/solved-how-to-use-ssl-support-without-manualy-building-qt-libraries/6

added CONFIG += openssl-linked
copied from the QtSdk the (MingW) libeay32.dll and ssleay32.dll in the same folder as the executable